# Print call stack when entering all functions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

There used to be a really cool utility for Mozilla called [`FireFlow`](https://blog.imaginea.com/fireflow/). FireFlow would monitor the callstack allowing you to see exactly how a webpage is working, no matter how complex the site.

This utility has since stopped working because it used to use [`JSD`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Add-ons/Code_snippets/JavaScript_Debugger_Service) which is now obsolete.

The general concept is simple:

Let a website contain the following `html`:

```
<html>
  <script>
    function doSomething(){
      logIt()
      console.log("done")
    }
    function logIt(){
      console.log("it")
    }
  </script>
  <button onclick="doSomething()">Click me</button>
</html>
```

If the button is clicked while `FireFlow` is running I'd expect a trace like this:

```
call doSomething
  call logIt
    call console.log
  call console.log
```

So I've been considering building this myself using [Chrome Debugger Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) and `console.trace()`. However, before I go and re-invent the wheel, does anyone know if such a tool already exists and is working?